# What is the FK for ContactsContract GroupMembership to Groups

Tags: android, contactscontract

For a row in ContactsContract.GroupMembership, how do I find the corresponding row in ContactsContract.Groups?

GroupMembership seems to have only to "key" columns: `GROUP_ROW_ID`, `GROUP_SOURCE_ID`.

The former has values like 14, 15, 16. The latter is 0.

The Groups table seems to have only `_ID`. This has values of 0, 1, 2, not in the same range as 14, 15 16.

Answer (score 0):

The FK actually is GROUP_ROW_ID. I had a "distraction" in my code.

I'm leaving this post here in case anyone else isn't sure about Google's documentation:

> The row id of the group that this group membership refers to.

What they mean instead of "group" is "ContactsContract.Groups row".